# why I use golang module, and import a module that is not opted in module, but go.sum file has go.mod file hash?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am now using golang 1.13 and use go module.

However, when I import a package (for example, a) that is **not** opted in go module, in go.sum file there is still two lines. Go module tells us that "Each known module version results in two lines in the go.sum file. The first line gives the hash of the module version's file tree. The second line appends "/go.mod" to the version and gives the hash of only the module version's (possibly synthesized) go.mod file. The go.mod-only hash allows downloading and authenticating a module version's go.mod file, which is needed to compute the dependency graph, without also downloading all the module's source code."

(https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_downloading_and_verification).

But this package is not a module, and so it does not have a go.mod file? For example, if I import package call "github.com/example/a" that is not a module, in go.sum file, it still has these two lines:

```
github.com/example/a v0.0.0-20190627063042-31896c4e4162 h1:rSqi2vQEpS+GAFKrLvmxzWW3OGlLI4hANnEf/ib/ofo=

github.com/example/a v0.0.0-20190627063042-31896c4e4162/go.mod h1:tcpxll8wcruwpPpWBbjAsWc1JbLHld/v9F+3rgLIr4c=
```

My question is, how the second line generated?

Answer (score 0):

`go.sum` contains the expected cryptographic checksums
of the content of specific module versions. Each time a dependency is
used, its checksum is added to go.sum if missing or else required to match
the existing entry in go.sum.

Every package/module is dependency and every dependency mean to be maintained with checksums in `go.sum` so whether it is package or module it would be maintained.

The sources would be downloaded in `$GOPATH/src` directory accordingly.

TRY -

Comment: But the second line is the hash of the only the module version's go.mod file. If it is just a normal package that is not opted in go module, it means that this package does not have a go.mod file. So how to calculate the hash of "go.mod file" of this package?

Answer (score 0):

Cause in into the `go.sum` file are written EVERY dependencies sum hash. The one related to your `go.mod` file, and the one imported from the modules that you have imported. Try run `go mod tidy` in order to reduce the imported modules, your `go.mod` file will contains some `//indirect` import, that are the one that your imported modules use internally.

Comment: But the second line is the hash of the only the module version's go.mod file. If it is just a normal package that is not opted in go module, it means that this package does not have a go.mod file. So how to calculate the hash of "go.mod file" of this package?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Golang source code can explain the reason:

```golang
func (r *codeRepo) legacyGoMod(rev, dir string) []byte {
    // We used to try to build a go.mod reflecting pre-existing
    // package management metadata files, but the conversion
    // was inherently imperfect (because those files don't have
    // exactly the same semantics as go.mod) and, when done
    // for dependencies in the middle of a build, impossible to
    // correct. So we stopped.
    // Return a fake go.mod that simply declares the module path.
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("module %s\n", modfile.AutoQuote(r.modPath)))
}
```

code from here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/acac535c3ca571beeb168c953d6d672f61387ef1/src/cmd/go/internal/modfetch/coderepo.go#L857

↓ VSCode open `/usr/local/go/src`:

1. locate to `cmd/go/internal/modfetch/coderepo.go`, add a breakpoint to func `legacyGoMod`
2. locate to `cmd/go/internal/modfetch/coderepo_test.go`, press F5
3. wait for a while, stop at the breakpoint

[image: VSCode debug Golang source code]